# How to select all elements in name array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to sum a collection of radio selections using jQuery.

```
<input name="cost[alpha]" type="radio" >
<input name="cost[beta]" type="radio">
<input name="cost[delta]" type="radio">
...
$('input[name="cost[*]"]').each( function() {
    ...
}
```

This does not function as it tries to resolve an input with the name "cost[*]". Ideally I would like to iterate over any element in the cost array. Is there a preferred way of doing this with jQuery? I have other elements in my form that use the radio type so selecting radios in general is not a valid option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the attribute selector the "[starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector (`^=`):

```
$('input[name^="cost"]').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

If you find that you have other input elements that start with "cost" or even "cost[", then perhaps you want to think about changing the way you're querying for the elements. One alternative would be adding a special class name to the elements you're targeting and forget about their names altogether. For example:

```
<input name="cost[alpha]" type="radio" class="form-cost">
<input name="cost[beta]" type="radio" class="form-cost">
<input name="cost[delta]" type="radio" class="form-cost">
```

And then your selector is very simple and very targeted:

```
$('input.form-cost').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

You might get the best performance out of simply wrapping the elements in a container with a unique id or class name, and querying for input elements that it contains (as suggested by [Allende](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462889/allende) in the comments):

```
<div id="cost-inputs">
    <input name="cost[alpha]" type="radio">
    <input name="cost[beta]" type="radio">
    <input name="cost[delta]" type="radio">
</div>

$('#cost-inputs input').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Damn you was faster than me. haha +1

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why using a start of the line match versus a glob "input[name*='cost[']" match as illustrated below would be beneficial? I wonder if this method would have issue if I had other fields with "cost" as the first four characters of their name.

Comment: @Benji: Good point. You might want to add a trailing '[' to avoid clashing with other inputs. If necessary, you could restrict it further by changing the selector to `input[type="radio"][name^="cost["]`. Generally a "starts-with" comparison algorithm is faster than a "contains" algorithm, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: If you are trying to count the amount of input you have you could add a counter to your function like so:  .each(function(counter) {

Comment: @Benji: I have edited with a suggested alternative if managing the names of the inputs becomes too cumbersome.

Comment: I think add an specific class or better yet to wrap them in a div will prevent the issue about naming collision and also probably will improve the performance (if radios are wrapped in a div you have no need to deal with selector expressions).

Comment: @Allende: Good suggestion; I will add it as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector in jquery

```
$("input[name*='cost[']").each(function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var sum = 0;
$("input[name^='cost']").each(function() {
     sum += Number($(this).val());
});
```

About "Starts With Selector": [name^="value"]
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/